# Installing GeoFire with cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods, geofire

I am currently trying to set up GeoFire with my Firebase project and have a podfile like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '[Appname]' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for [Appname]
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'GeoFire', '~> 1.1'

end
```

However, running a pod install command gives this error:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase (~> 2.1)` required by `GeoFire (1.1.0)`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase (~> 2.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I can't figure out how to get GeoFire installed. Isn't GeoFire compatible with the new Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```